# C++ Diamond Inheritance - Share variables with another non base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual, ambiguous

This is my first post on stackoverflow so be gentle :)

I have standard diamond problem but I'd managed to sort it out.

```
class Control  
{ 
  public:  
    bool Focused;  
};

class Caption : public virtual Control  
{
  public:  
    string Text;  
};

class Frame : public virtual Control { };

class Textbox : public Caption, public Frame, public TextEditor { };
```

Sadly another problem with inheritance appeared. Class `TextEditor` has common variable names:

```
class TextEditor
{
  public:
    bool Focused;  
    string Text;  
};
```

Compiler gives me errors:

> ambiguous access of 'Text'
>
> ambiguous access of 'Focused'

But all I want is those variables from all classes to be merged in derived class 'Textbox'.

> [Here's link to the UML picture with the problem](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/8706/ksq2.jpg)

Thanks for any kind of help
Sorry for any languages mistakes and/or question I'm asking.

**Update**

A little explanation cause I might have use wrong words. Sorry for that.

By 'merge' I meant that:

- If I use variables or methods of `Control`, `Caption` or `Frame` it will influence the values of `TextEditor` and vice versa. In other words variables are shared in derived class.

So my final class will look like this:

```
class Textbox : public Caption, public Frame, public TextEditor  
{  
  public:   
    string Text;  
    bool Focused;  
};
```

And not like this:

```
class Textbox : public Caption, public Frame, public TextEditor  
{  
  public:   
    string Caption::Text;   
    bool Caption::Focused;  
    string TextEditor::Text;  
    bool TextEditor::Focused;  
};
```

Which happening right now. Cause I can't do this:

```
Textbox A;
A.Text = "Text";
```

Because I have two variables with the name `Text`. So I would have to do this:

```
Textbox A;
A.Caption::Text = "Text";
A.TextEditor::Text = "Text";
```

Best regards
Lavi

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which point of 'how to ask' I have violated ? Question is specific. I've reaseched over internet about this problem what else ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ambiguous class inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793651/ambiguous-class-inheritance)

Comment: How do you want these variables to be "merged"? When you reference the variable `Text` in a method of `Textbox`, which one should the compiler use? They cannot simply be both merged, since `TextEditor::Text` is used for something different than `Caption::Text`. If you would merge these variables, methods of `Caption` could influence the value of `TextEditor::Text`

Comment: @Mgetz - Diamond problem has been sorted already in my case. I've said that in my question. This problem can be considered as an extension of that problem

Comment: @Alexander Weinert - This exaclty what I want :)

Comment: @Lavi please check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100278/how-can-i-improve-my-question-when-there-is-no-feedback-left-by-downvoters also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I up voted but you should improve your question. I read many times but still do not quite understand what do you want to do with those variables.

Comment: @khajvah The problem may be in the word I've used 'merged'. I want to achieve the thing which 'Alexander Weinert' said at the end of his comment. If I use variables, methods of `Caption` it will influence the values of `TextEditor`.

Comment: @Lavi it sounds like you've found how you should fix your question, clarity matters a lot, as does showing what behavior you're intending to achieve and what you've tried previously. Don't be afraid of being verbose. [The guide I linked earlier](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) is really a good way of approaching asking a question.

Comment: @Mgetz But sometimes you may lack of right words especialy if you're not native English speaker or you don't know the words you should use. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes:

1. Consider using [mutator methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method)
2. Please http://sscce.org/ - your example seems a bit over the show - would be easier to give you a clear example of how to solve your problem if your example in the problem was infact sscce. Either way, its still sufficient and your problem is clear enough I guess.

Answers:

1. Why does `class TextEditor` not also inherit from `class Control` and `class Caption` ? This would seem like the obvious solution - you would have to use virtual inheritance for `class TextBox`  still though.
2. If 1 is not an option - then there is this - but in this limited sample HasText and Focusable seems to be pointless when compared to Caption and Control respectively.

   ```
   class HasText
   {   
   public:
       virtual string& text() { return text; }
       virtual const string& text() const { return text; }
   private:
       text
   };  

   class Focusable
   {   
   public:
       virtual bool& focused() { return focused; }
       virtual const bool& focussed() const { return focussed; }
   };  

   class Control : public virtual Focusable { };

   class Caption : public virtual Control, public virtual HasText { };

   class Frame : public virtual Control { };

   class TextEditor : public virtual HasText, public virtual Focusable { };

   class Textbox : public virtual Caption, public virtual Frame, public virtual TextEditor { };
   ```

Comment: Second option would require from me to redesign whole GUI API. In my case first option couldn't be used either. So the only thing for me is to duplciate `TextEditor` code, strip it apart so it can inherit `Caption`. I wanted to avoid that but sometime you need to take step back in order to move forward. Anyway thanks for your ideas and help :)

Comment: If you were using mutator methods throughout this might also have provided an option.