# Why doesn't 'using A::X' avoid ambiguity with multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, ambiguity

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793651/ambiguous-class-inheritance) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46646773/avoid-multiple-inheritance-induced-ambiguity-by-using-scope-resolution), but I think (hope!) different enough to deserve an explanation.

I have a complex configuration framework, with decorator classes used to implement some common, simple actions (like flagging when a class Set accessor is called).  I'm trying to introduce a new decorator (rather than a composition), which itself "should" inherit from that same common "Set-flagging" decorator.

I'm running into "ambiguous conversion from derived class to base class", and my attempts to work around it have failed.
I'm missing something obvious, I'm sure.

Here's a very simple example, without all my framework stuff.

```
class A {
public:
  template <class T> void Set(T& arg, T val);
  bool Ready() const;
};

class B : private A {
  // Does stuff where I want to flag Set() actions
};

class C : public B, public A {
  // This class needs the B interface, and the Set()-flagging
public:
  void SetParam(double val) { Set(param, val); }

private:
  double param;
};
```

Note that I original used virtual inheritance of A, but in practice I need to keep the "Set-flag" for B distinct from the "Set-flag" for C, hence my attempt above.

The private inheritance above was my first attempt to avoid the ambiguity.  I also tried introducing using directives in C:

```
class C : public B, public A {
  // This class needs the B interface, and the Set()-flagging
  using A::Set;
  using A::Ready;
};
```

This doesn't change the error.  I understand from searching that the ambiguity is caught before the public/private state is checked.  But I thought that the explicit `using` directives would resolve it.  Why doesn't it?  Do I need to go in and use `A::Set(...)` or `A::Ready()` explicitly everywhere?

Comment: The problem is that it is the `A` that is ambiguous -- it could be either the direct base `A` or `B::A`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just: `class B : public A`, `class C : public B`? Must `B` only inherit `private` from `A`?

Comment: *"But I thought that the explicit `using` directives would resolve it."* -- The directives don't resolve it so much as save you from typing `A::Set(...)` or `A::Ready()` everywhere. The directive `using A::Set;` means (more or less) "when you see `Set`, read it as `A::Set`". If the directive does not resolve the ambiguity, then neither will writing out `A::Set`.

Comment: @Frodyne I had that originally.  In my real application, it turns out that in C I need to keep track of parameter changes to B separately from all the other changes to A.  I will likely end up having to make C has-a B, but I wanted to be sure I could not use the decorator pattern for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions.

If you really want to keep the private and multiple inheritance:

```
class A {
public:
    void Set() {};
    bool Ready() const {};
};

class B : private A {
};

class C : public B, public A {
public:
    void SetParam() { C::A::Set(); }
};
```

Or if that is not needed, then a simpler one:

```
class A {
public:
    void Set() {};
    bool Ready() const {};
};

class B : public A {
};

class C : public B {
public:
    void SetParam() { Set(); }
};
```

Comment: These look like the correct "structural" solutions for the class hierarchy I outlined.  For my specific application I changed class C to use a composition: it directly inherits from A, but uses a B data member in order to keep the two "Set-flag" values distinct.